# Correct way to manage routes after sign in for different roles

Tags: meteor, roles, iron-router

I have 2 roles, admins and users. I have a home route `'/'` that is just a sign in page. When admin users sign in they must go to one route (`'adminPortal'`) and when user users log in they must go to the `'userPortal'` route. On signing out both roles should route back to `'/'`.

Before I had an admin role, I was routing on sign in like so:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  this.render('loading');
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('Home');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

which worked fine (actually it was breaking my `waitOn:` render loading template stuff which I just discovered but more on that later). I then added roles like this (from a Stack Overflow answer I can't find right now):

**server/**

```
insertUsers=function(){
  var adminId=Accounts.createUser({
    username:"admin",
    password:"password"
  });

  Roles.addUsersToRoles(adminId,"admin");

  var userIdd = Accounts.createUser({
    username:"user",
    password:"password"
  });

  Roles.addUsersToRoles(userIdd,"user");

};
```

and

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  // always start from scratch (you will want to comment this line at some point !)
  Meteor.users.remove({});
  if(Meteor.users.find().count()===0){
    insertUsers();
  }
})
```

and

```
Meteor.publish("user", function () {
  if (this.userId) {
    return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                             {fields: {'roles': 1}});
  } else {
    this.ready();
  }
});
```

And I tried to route to the user/admin portals like this:

**router.js**

```
Router.route('/', {

  before: function() {
    if (! Meteor.userId()) {  // I acutally added this check that the user is not logged in after the infinite loading problem but I thought the question was getting too long so I just left it in rather
      this.render('Home')
    } else {
      if (Roles.userIsInRole(Meteor.user(), 'admin')) {
        Router.go('/admin')
      } else {
        Router.go('/user')
      }
    }
  },

  waitOn: function () {
    return Meteor.subscribe('user');
  }

});
```

Now this very almost works! If I log is as either user I go to the right portal. However, when I sign out, my `onBeforeAction` (i.e. first code block in this question) only renders the `Home` template and does not actually change the URL to `'/'` (i.e. the URL remains either `'/user'` or `'/admin'`). Now when I try log in a second time, it will always take me to the route that I was taken to on the first log in unless I manually change the browser URL to `'/'`. So I thought I'd just replace the `this.render('Home')` with a `Router.go('/');` but that seems to have created some sort of infinite loop where the `Home` template never renders (it did incidentally now for the first time correctly render my loading template though).

So thanks for reading all that! What's the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `Router.go('/');` in your logout button event, along with `Meteor.logout();`

Example:

```
Template.loginButtons.events({
    'click #login-buttons-logout' : function (event, template) {
        Meteor.logout(function(err) {
            Router.go('/');
        });
    }
});
```

I had the same issue as you, and that was the simplest way I've found to return to home page after logout.

Comment: Oh forgot to mention that I actually did try this, but not sure when, it might have been before some of the other stuff. I couldn't get it to work though. Can you comment on if my `onBeforeAction` code btw?

Comment: Wait just to clarify, the "logout button event" and `Meteor.logout()` is one thing right? Because I only tried the `Meteor.logout()`, so if there is a different logout button event that I can try?

Comment: I have a custom logout button, calling `Router.go('chamados.todos');` (my home template) and `Meteor.logout();`

Comment: Thinking about it, you can use `onBeforeAction` of `/admin` and `/user` routes. I'll edit my answer

Comment: I see, what I had tried is `Meteor.logout(function(err) { Router.go('/'); });` but not in a click event. I'll wait to see your update, but do you know how to edit the `sign out` click event of the standard `loginButtons` form? Or should I rather just make my own form like you've done?

Comment: Looked at your edit, not sure I understand because then wouldn't I need to put that on every single route i the application? And do you mean I should leave my `Router.onBeforeAction` code as it is?

Comment: I understood "using `onBeforeAction`" now. Sorry :) Let me look at documentation

Comment: Oh.. I've looked at your question.. You've already tried this.. Let me think another solution..

Comment: Ya that does the same as router.go :( I'm going to try your idea with the button click event... will report back

Comment: Got it! `Template.loginButtons.events ({
    "click #login-buttons-logout" : function (event, template) {
      Meteor.logout(function(err) {
        Router.go('/');
      });
    }
  })`. Feel free to add this to your answer and I'll accept!