# Routing to home screen when not signed in

Tags: meteor, iron-router, user-accounts

I want to redirect all users to a home page if they are not logged in. Currently I am doing this:

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  this.render('loading');
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('Home');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
});
```

Which I saw online, but this seems to be prevent my `'loading'` template from ever showing and instead shows the default

> Loading...

in the top left of the screen. If I change `this.render('Home');` to `this.redirect('/')` I see the correct loading template. However in the `'/'` route I call another `this.render('Home')` which I think then triggers the `onBeforeAction` again which in turn will redirect to `'/'` which means you are now in an infinite loop of loading.

So what is the correct way to fix my `Router.onBeforeAction` to achieve my desried goal of making sure users that are not logged in can only see the `Home` template no matter what URL they type in and do this without messing up my custom loading template elsewhere on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have two before hooks. One is for 'loading' and one is to check if the user is logged in.

The 'loading' one is linked up to your subscriptions and is usually a preinstalled hook with iron router.

```
Router.onBeforeAction(function() {
  if (! Meteor.userId()) {
    this.render('Home');
  } else {
    this.next();
  }
}, {except: ['route_one', 'route_two']});

Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

Your route:

```
Router.route('/', {
    name: 'home',
    subscriptions: function() { 
        //Array of Meteor.subscribe to wait for and display the loading template
        return [Meteor.subscribe("a_subscription")]
    },
    loadingTemplate: 'loading',
    action: function() {
        this.render("Home_logged_in");
    }
});
```

So here, if `Meteor.subscribe("a_subscription")` is loading it will display the `loading` template. If the user is logged in it will display the `Home_logged_in` template and if not logged in (on any route) the `Home` template.

You can also set exceptions using the names 'route_one' and 'route_two' for your templates (which you can rename to anything else). I named your home template `home`. But if you added `home` to the `except` list the onBeforeAction would not apply to `home`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this tonight after work. Just for some more context, this question has more of my code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30512782/correct-way-to-manage-routes-after-sign-in-for-different-roles. I seem to have a slightly different format for my `route`s. Would you recommend I change them to match yours?

Comment: @Dan its the same format you can use either waitOn or subscriptions the result should be the same. You may need to add in `loadingTemplate` and `name`. I also recommend you use an `action` for your routes like above instead of using `before` as the pattern you're using is slightly dated.

Answer (score 1):

I use this `onBeforeAction` hook which redirect to the home page if the user is not logged in:

```
var userAuthHook = function() {
  if (Meteor.userId()) {
    //continue to the requested url
    this.next();
  } else {
    //redirect to home
    this.redirect('/');
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(userAuthHook, {
  except: ['home']
});

Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home'
});
```

Note that I exclude the home page from the hook in order to avoid redirect loops and that the `/` route is named "home" to be referred to in the hook exclusions.

This works for me and also allows to use loading templates.

Comment: Thanks I'll try it when I'm home later. I was trying to use `except` (although differently) but I hadn't named my routes, maybe that was the issue